# PHP - Is it possible to flip only a specific part of a key value array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array, key-value, array-flip

Lets say I have the following array:

```
$array_1 = [         
         'Green' => 'Tea',
         'Apple' => 'Juice',
         'Black' => 'Coffee',
      ];
```

How do I flip the key => value of only one part of the array to something like this:

```
   $array_2 = [         
         'Tea' => 'Green',
         'Apple' => 'Juice',
         'Black' => 'Coffee',
      ];
```

I know there is a function `array_flip()` but it flips the whole array, how do I go about flipping only a selected key value pair in the array?

Comment: What is the logic for which keys should be flipped?

Comment: @Barmar Currently no logic - I'm simply asking out of curiosity as I'm new to PHP and noticed `array_flip()` only does the whole array

Comment: There's nothing built-in. Just add the new element and delete the old one.

Answer (score 2):

The following code just `flips` all elements of the array. It just does the same thing as `array_flip`:

```
$array_2 = array();
foreach ($array_1 as $key => $value) {
    $array_2[$value] = $key;
}
```

Now if you want to flip an element in the array, you need to code like the following. Suppose you want to flip just `'Apple'` in your element. You need to wait for that element in a `foreach` loop, and when you catch it, flip it. Try the following just to flip the 'Apple' key.

```
    $array_2 = array();
    foreach ($array_1 as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'Apple') {
            $array_2[$value] = $key;
        } else {
            $array_2[$key] = $value;
    
        }
    }
```

[Try this online!](https://tio.run/##bZAxa8MwEIV3/Yo3GJxAISSr65a2QyFzoUMIQbgnrERIQpJbQslvd6UzytSbxHvf3b2TH/08Pz770QvRyBDk9bRFj4NArvY9ENkW/RPaD5Ltw6K@eG9oUfeTHqjqr0YOl0V/c0pRMY5dHbvLY/m1WndCbDb4JJynmPAjbUJyUEZ7pJFwoet9ibRfsA4u66EYkZVvaSaK0JZ5niqUCySHEav7GTKiKbNyoIY71vjlpFplip2@r5uqV6omPixtx5y84B0DN5CJ9C@dGWa5Kx/JuLgJH7RNp1CT7fIHzPMf)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing that does this. Just assign the flipped key and delete the old key.

```
$key_to_flip = 'Green';
$array_2 = $array_1;
unset($array_2[$key_to_flip]);
$array_2[$array_1[$key_to_flip]] = $key_to_flip;
```